# How to add a custom shape or background to bottom of current menu item

Tags: css, nav, pseudo-element

I want to add some kind of thick line underneath my currently active`<li>` items. Problem is, I can't set it up properly. I want the line underneath to inherit the width of its respective `<li>` or at least to be centered ...

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx4TZ/1/)

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an absolutely positioned element to inherit the width of it's parent, you need to position that parent relatively. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). For your situation, you need to :

1. Add `position:relative;` to `.nav li`
2. Add `width :100%; left:0;` and remove `margin-left: -6em;` on  `nav li.current a:after, nav li a:hover:after`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/yx4TZ/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be adding the `:after` content in two places which seems excessive.

Since you only want in on active `1i` you can strip down your code as follows:

**CSS**

```
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 1.25em;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

nav li a {
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1em 1.25em;
    width: auto;
}

nav li.current a, nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

nav li.current:after {
    background-color:black;
    content: "";
    height: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yx4TZ/4/)

Comment: okay, i get that. if I had an image below the nav, how would I make the black bar overlap the image?

Comment: Image below the nav...what is a separate section / div you mean? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yx4TZ/7/

Comment: I'd have a `<header>` wrapped around that nav I was asking about and another `<section>` with e.g a different background color following. the black bars from the active `<li>` elements don't come to the foreground, they are behind the `<section>`

Comment: Perhaps you could show us in a JSfiddle but it sounds like you just need to add a `z-index`value to the `:after`?